# ¿Cómo establecer una página principal por medio de htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-plugin

Quisiera establecer una página del sitio como la principal a través de htaccess, ya que en wordpress, dentro de ajustes--lectura no aparece.

Quisiera que se redirija a **dominio.com/Negocio** 
y de ser posible que **/negocio** quede oculto o no se muestre.
Si por ahi existe un plugin que haga esto les agradecería.
Este es mi archivo .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: según no mal entendí tu deseas establecer un directorio /negocio en el htaccess  como pagina por defecto?

Comment: Así es amigo sería tal cual lo dices

Answer (score 0):

Como deseas que inicie el wp en negocio puedes usar el siguiente .htaccess, el cual usa esta carpeta de negocios como inicio en el wp y en la usa en la pagina principal para que no aparezca:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /negocio/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /negocio/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

esa es la opción por .htaccess, pero desde la personalización del tema también lo puedes hacer, en la opción de página de inicio.

Comment: debes explicar tu código, por que esas líneas resuelven el problema? recuerda que responder solo con código es de baja calidad

Comment: ojo no uses una etiqueta p para poner tu código eso es confuso, debes seleccionarlo y darle formato con `{}`